# how to remove "My First App" in heroku app

Tags: facebook, heroku

I just made a facebook app on heroku but facing some problem. Whenever I invoke the message or feed dialogue, Description of my app appears as "**My First App**". I've looked my code thoroughly but have not find this string anywhere. I've changes the og_description to my own but still getting it.
Even when I try to post the link, the description appears as that.
Where would be the problem.

Comment: Have you looked in your application's settings?

Answer (score 2):

> Description of my app appears as "My First App"

Well, than that’s obviously the name of your app. If you don’t like it, change it in your app’s settings under https://developers.facebook.com/apps

> Even when I try to post the link, the description appears as that. Where would be the problem.

If you post anything through an app, the *“via appname”* text *always* appears. There is nothing you can “do” about that – it’s *meant* to be that way.

Comment: _Via appname_ is appearing as it should be and the name is different too.